# Cannot see Ryzen 7700 integrated gpu driver - ubuntu 22

Tags: drivers, graphics, cpu, gpu-driver, amd-ryzen

Is it a rule that AMD on Linux always has problem?. I am testing the latest ubuntu 22 kernel however it can't see the graphics card instead in the **Display section I have Unknown Device** so I can't even connect a second monitor.

section about system: graphic : **llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6, 256 bits)**

Settings tab shows [img][https://i.imgur.com/UkzSinD.png[/img]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSqxL.png)
[img][https://i.imgur.com/Akow11D.png[/img]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7NVY.png)

**sudo lshw -c video**

```
 *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
  
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fc0-fbf memory:fce0000000-fcefffffff memory:fcf0000000-fcf01fffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fce00000-fce7ffff
  *-graphics
```

// I have read some advice and am trying to install the amd driver however I get this error in the logs when I do the dpkg configure command

```
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
  You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.16.9.22.20-1438747~22.04/build/Makefile:16: *** dma_resv->seq is missing., exit....  Stop.
```

Comment: Not sure, but since NVIDIA and wayland do not work together,maybe AMD has the same problem.  Try to switch your session to X11 (log out, change the session and log in again)

Comment: but what then? install driver or ?

Comment: still got "dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):"

Comment: You should not install a graphics driver this way. That package doesn't make sense anyhow. Purge it. Use the "hardware" app & check if a driver exists. BTW: I'm running a ThinkPad with AMD GPU and do not have any problems. . But you should refrain from installing software if you don't know what it does.

Comment: On the manufacturer's website there is no driver under Linux. The hardrwine tab on ubuntu also shows nothing for isntalation - I have an unknowd device. So lame these new systems and hardware

Comment: You might need another kernel for this, since AMD provides it there. Check [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/gpu/amdgpu/driver-misc.html)